# Error trying to link a container using Dokku

Tags: docker, dokku

I am trying to create a link to access a service running in another container. The command I am using is:

`dokku docker-options:add service deploy,build,run --link service.unoserver.1:unoserver_host`

and then

`dokku ps:restart service`

However, for some reason, dokku keeps adding a number at the end of the container's name (problbly the name of the replacing container) and I receive the following error message:

### Error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /service.unoserver.1.1695992273 AS /sevice.prepareworker.1/unoserver_host
```

### Question:

How can I link the container `service.unoserver.1` so I can access it from the container `service.preparewoker.1`?

`docker container ls`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
f47bb2ec5626   dokku/service:latest   "unoserver --interfa…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   5000/tcp   service.unoserver.1
d35c1a242d52   dokku/service:latest   "python manage.py ru…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   5000/tcp   service.prepareworker.1
```

Comment: Is this the standard Docker "link" option, or something Dokku-specific?  Docker links are an artifact of first-generation Docker networking and I'd consider them obsolete at this point; named Docker networks functionally replace them.

Comment: @DavidMaze it is a docker standard option. This dokku command adds the link option as argument. The curious thing is that it works for the database. I can access the database container from another container. There is a link to the postgres container:    `"/dokku.postgres.setvice:/service.prepareworker.1/dokku-postgres-service" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networking across containers requires a stable container name when using docker link. For this reason, Dokku only uses them for service linking.

If you want to network across apps, you’ll want to use networks. The following would be enough to create a network and add your app to it:

```bash
# create a network named my-network
dokku network:create my-network

# attach the app to it
dokku network:set node-js-app attach-post-deploy my-network
```

From then on, the app node-js-app would be accessible on the network at `http://node-js-app.web:5000`, where `web` is the process type and `5000` is the port the app is listening on inside the container. You can attach other apps to that same network to connect to this service.

See the [dokku network management docs](https://dokku.com/docs/networking/network/) for more details on how this works.